# What is causing the interrupt on my esp32 to trigger immediately after activating a relay?

Tags: relay, esp32

I am attempting to build a circuit that:

1. Allows me to use a momentary switch to toggle Christmas lights on and off.
2. Allows me to control the lights (on/off) using a web browser.

An ESP32 seemed like a good choice, so I used the following parts and put it all together:

- an ESP32-WROOM-32
- SN74AHCT125N logic level shifter (ESP32 pins operate at 3.3V, relay needs 5V)
- [this relay board](https://www.amazon.ca/Huayao-Channel-Optocoupler-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B07DN8DTRW)

My (rough) attempt at a schematic looks like this (sorry, part of the switch got cut off):

[image]

And assembled on a breadboard, it looks like this (pardon the Frankenstein breadboard, it was the only way I could get the ESP32 board to fit in a usable configuration):

[image]

Without going into a lot of the code, I've basically got an interrupt handler set up like this:

```
pinMode(PIN_BUTTON, INPUT_PULLUP);
attachInterrupt(PIN_BUTTON, handler, CHANGE);
```

The interrupt handler adds an item to a queue running in a task which writes `HIGH` to the output pin controlling the relay.

The good news is that the momentary switch works perfectly. The bad news is that the web interface does not. When the command is received, the relay activates (you can hear the click) and immediately turns the load off within a fraction of a second. The interrupt handler seems to be triggered, implying voltage on the switch portion of the circuit. The ESP32 doesn't seem to be affected in any way, based on serial debug output.

I'm not sure what could be causing this. I have a flyback diode in place. I've tried using resistors to no avail. What could be causing this?

Comment: No decoupling capacitor around HCT125 ... and around relay box.

Comment: Does it still do the bad thing when there is no load connected i.e. can you hear the relay click on and off or does it in-fact work (albeit no load)?

Comment: @Andyaka good idea! I checked by unplugging the load from the wall and the relay seems to work as intended, based on the clicking and status LED on the board. I also noticed that it activated the relay when I reconnected the load.

Comment: Try adding a 100 uF electrolytic capacitor across the 5 volt power rail near the relay module.

Comment: @Andyaka unfortunately I don't have one on hand but I've put in an order for some and I'll update in a couple days when it arrives :)

Comment: Using interrupts on switch inputs is bad juju. Interrupts give you sub microsecond response whereas the mechanical switch is tens of milliseconds. As you’ve observed, any glitch will trigger the interrupt. Use a timer interrupt to sample the switch gpio input in your code at a regular interval. Also note your ‘relay’ already has the required diode on its pcb. Adding another on the power supply does very little.

Comment: @Andyaka I tried putting one across the 5V and GND connections next to the relay, sadly no luck. Would there be any benefit to putting one across the GPIO used for the button and ground?

Comment: When you say you unplugged the load from the wall (comment) I'm not sure how that fits-in with your schematic.